# dialogflow how to play the next time available from google calendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, webhooks

how are you? English are my native language, so I apologize right away.

what I have is a bot in the dialogflow, which with some interactions marks events on the agenda.

**an example:**

**Bot:** hello welcome to the hairdresser, would you like to make an appointment?

**User:** *Yes*

**Bot:** What's your name?

**User**: *Welyson*

**Bot:** What day would you like?

**User:** *tomorrow*

**Bot:** What time?

**User:** *3pm*

- If you have space on the google calendar

**Bot:** Okay, you were scheduled for February 21st at 3pm

-If you don't have space on the google calendar

**Bot:** Oops, it appears that we have no vacancies for that day or time, type **check** to try another time.

[Where I got the code as an example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbots-dialogflow-fulfillment/#0)

**The code below does this:**

```
 'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const {google} = require('googleapis');
 const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

 // Enter your calendar ID below and service account JSON below
 const calendarId = "id google agenda ";
 const serviceAccount = {json file}; // Starts with {"type": "service_account",...

 // Set up Google Calendar Service account credentials
 const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
   email: serviceAccount.client_email,
   key: serviceAccount.private_key,
   scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
 });

 const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
 process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements

 const timeZoneOffset = '-03:00';

 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
   const appointment_nome = agent.parameters.nome;


   function makeAppointment (agent) {
     const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
     const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
     const agendamentoString = FormtData(new Date(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0])) + " às " + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0]; 

     // Check the availibility of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
     return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_nome).then(() => {
       let mensagem = `Okay, you were scheduled for *${agendamentoString}* ✅.`;
       response.json({"fulfillmentText": mensagem});
     }).catch(() => {
        let mensagem = `Oops, it appears that we have no vacancies for that day or time, type **check** to try another time.`;
       response.json({"fulfillmentText": mensagem});
     });
   }

   let intentMap = new Map();
   //intentMap.set('Schedule Appointment', makeAppointment);  
   intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent - yes', makeAppointment);
   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
 });



 function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_nome) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     calendar.events.list({
       auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
       calendarId: calendarId,
       timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
       timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
     }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
       // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
       if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
         reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));

       } else {
         // Create event for the requested time period
         calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
           calendarId: calendarId,
           resource: {summary:"Cliente: " +  appointment_nome, description: "Cliente: " +  appointment_nome,
             start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
             end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
         }, (err, event) => {
           err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
         }
         );
       }
     });
   });
 }

 function FormtData(date){
    var nomesMes = [
        "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", 
        "Abril", "Maio", "Junho","Julho", 
        "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", 
        "Novembro", "Dezembro"
    ];

    var dia = date.getDate();
    var mesIndex = date.getMonth();
    var ano = date.getFullYear();

    return dia + ' ' + nomesMes[mesIndex];

 }
```

But **the problem** is that if my schedule has too many times scheduled, the schedule will become tiring for the user!

I thought of something, like

**Bot:** Would you like to schedule a haircut?

**User:** yes

**Bot:** How about February 21st at 1 pm?

-If the user **agrees** the time is marked in the agenda:

**User:** *Yes*

**Bot:** Okay, you were scheduled for February 21st at 1pm

-If the user **disagrees** he goes to the next available time:

**User:** *No*

**Bot:** How about February 21st at 2 pm?

I tried something with the [CalDAV API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) to read the google calendar, I didn't get any progress
Does anyone have any idea how I would do this? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `But the problem is that if my schedule has too many times scheduled, the schedule will become tiring for the user!`. Can I ask you about your current issue and your goal? By the way, `google-apps-script` is included in your tags. How do you want to use the Google Apps Script for achieving your goal?

Comment: Example of my problem: think of a google calendar where there are many full slots, as I still don't know how to check for empty slots, the user would be trying to schedule through the dialogflow until he finds an available slot, my goal is instead of leaving the user chooses the times, I check the available ones and offer to the user and ask if it is good.

Comment: the use of google-apps-script would be for an implementation using the google spreadsheet where I mark the times in the spreadsheet and the script throws them to the agenda, the verification would be done in the spreadsheet instead of the agenda.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your goal. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: did you managed to solve it?